# Dynamically Bind extern(Objective-C) Classes in D

Tags: objective-c, linker, d

I want to make heavy use of `extern (Objective-C)` classes in my D app as I don't want to deal with manually sending Objective-C messages. However, I'm mainly using frameworks like AppKit, IOKit, and Foundation, and `extern (Objective-C)` requires static linking in order to work according to the [documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/objc_interface.html).

But, I don't think statically linking OS libraries is a very good idea. It seems pretty fragile when considering different macOS versions.

So my questions are,

1. Is it actually a bad idea to statically link Foundation and AppKit?
2. If yes to one, then is it possible to dynamically load a .framework file with `dlopen` and then bind the function pointers to `extern (Objective-C)` classes?

Comment: As an alternative to ```extern``` you could perhaps look at using singletons?

Comment: @skaak That doesn't seem relevant to my question. `extern` is a way of changing the name mangling for the linker from D to Objective-C.

Comment: Yes apologies. I was thinking to do all of the interfacing to Objective-C via some singleton somewhere but that does not change or help much.

Comment: Where in the documentation is the static linking requirement?

Comment: @Willeke Starting at https://dlang.org/spec/objc_interface.html#frameworks all of the examples shown are passing the frameworks to the linker at compilation. If dynamic linking is possible, it's not shown.

Comment: It says "A framework contains a dynamic library".

Comment: @Willeke Sure, but when you pass a compiled shared library to the linker statically I'm pretty sure the linker includes all of the symbols and code in the resulting binary. I was under the impression that dynamically calling shared libraries had to be done manually with `dlopen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. I don't think it is a problem, it's relatively standard practice. Of course then you won't be able to build for (say) both macOS and iOs in the same binary, but that is a rare situation. If you `dlopen` frameworks, you might find that they also sometimes move in macOS versions. Apple *will* have other ways to break your backwards compatibility from time to time, but removing frameworks under you is not common.
   You'll be one of the first lucky users of extern(Objective-C).
2. Yes, this is absolutely possible. But then you have to talk to the ObjC runtime directly because no functions are exported since OSX, only classes ID. You have to write a bit of brittle code for every method you want to call. Inheriting from protocols is very difficult. You really can't do much that way. On the plus side, it works the same in both DMD and LDC. You can check in `dplug:cocoa`. I really recommend to use extern(Objective-C) and static linking instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, say I build an executable with static linking on Big Sur and want to distribute it. Would Mojave users be able to run it no problem? Or would I have to build different executables for each macOS version supported?

Comment: If there is a x86_64 version in your Universal Binary 2 it will work down to macOS 10.12

Comment: Frameworks are not statically linked, they are statically *bound*. The OS just dlopens it for you at load time with this style, no actual code from the library is included in your application.

Comment: oh and I should add, with extern(Objective-C), the only symbols it even pulls in that way are a handful of runtime loader things. So it loads a runtime loader to look up dynamic symbols. It matches based on selector name rather than index slot or anything like that so you need only define the few things you need. It might not be 100% compatible but it should be pretty close.